# Software to handle snmp

Tags: grails, snmp

I want to find a software that handles snmp for me. In my grails software I want to handle snmp traps, poll snmp from devices, and send snmp traps.

The software should have some interfaces to collect the data. We are using ActiveMq,this would also be an option to get the data.

I found opennms, but it looks the software does much more than I need, which is not necessary.

I already looked at snmp4j. With this library I can program my own software for this, but I wonder if there is already a program which will fit my purposes.

Any ideas?

Best regards, 
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any plans to implement your own Trap Receiver I'd suggest using **NET-SNMP, SNMP++ or SNMP4J** frameworks. Please also note that these frameworks do not support parsing of **SMIv1, SMIv2** MIB files. So you'll have to implement your own MIB parser or use an exisiting one to do that. There are few open source MIB parsers but they are poorly implemented. So the parsing accuracy is real bad. I'd suggest using commercial SNMP products for enterprise-grade projects.

There are many SNMP products on the market. The industry standard product for SNMP traps handling is **NetDecision TrapVision**. Find out more at: http://www.netmechanica.com/products/?prod_id=1003 . It does many things:

- Fully supports SNMPv1, SNMPv2C, SNMPv3 (USM and VACM)
- Ultra high performance (thousands traps per minute)
- Resolves incoming SNMP traps based on MIB definitions (You can load any MIB files both standard and enterprise specific)
- You can filter out SNMP traps
- You can write incoming traps to DB or log file
- You can configure rules (trap handlers) to execute custom actions on the reception of a SNMP trap like email, sms, etc
- You can assign severity to a trap based on rules
- You can acknowledge and clear SNMP traps via GUI.
- You can assign troubleshooting information to a particular trap
- SNMP traps are displayed in modern GUI. You can manage SNMP notifications as easy as emails in MS Outlook.
- etc